# Android Studio Emulator too Many Errors

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hello everyone i have android studio emulator errors how can i fix those problems ?
I have amd ryzen 7 3700 u cpu
amd radeon vega 10 hd graphic cards
You can check my sdk list here;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zleN.png)

```
12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkBindBufferMemory2 not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkBindImageMemory2 not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkGetDeviceGroupPeerMemoryFeatures not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkCmdSetDeviceMask not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkCmdDispatchBase not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkGetImageMemoryRequirements2 not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements2 not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkGetImageSparseMemoryRequirements2 not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkTrimCommandPool not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkCreateSamplerYcbcrConversion not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkDestroySamplerYcbcrConversion not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkCreateDescriptorUpdateTemplate not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkDestroyDescriptorUpdateTemplate not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkUpdateDescriptorSetWithTemplate not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkGetDescriptorSetLayoutSupport not found

12:09 AM    Emulator: createOrGetGlobalVkEmulation: Warning: Vulkan 1.1 APIs missing from device
```

I couldn't solve those problems i tried many times

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. any solution as of yet?